# How to use SailsJs with firebase functions

Tags: firebase, sails.js

I'm trying to create nodejs app with sails.js and firebase. Cannot understand how to access express part of SailsJs.

Firebase app initialized by

```
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

app - express app.

Sails app initialized by

```
sails.lift(rc('sails'));
```

Tried to access to sails.hooks.http.app but it is undefined. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

hi you can use this piece of code to to execute fire base messaging services and in same manner other services too

```
var request = require('request');

    function sendMessageToUser(deviceId, message) {
    request({
    url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type' :' application/json',
    'Authorization': 'key=AI...8o'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(
    { "data": {
    "message": message
    },
    "to" : deviceId
    }
    )
    }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) { 
    console.error(error, response, body); 
    }
    else if (response.statusCode >= 400) { 
    console.error('HTTP Error: '+response.statusCode+' - '+response.statusMessage+'\n'+body); 
    }
    else {
    console.log('Done!')
    }
    });

    sendMessageToUser(
    "d7x...KJQ",
    { message: 'Hello puf'}
    );
```

as sails provide a method mentioned below ,but i was not able find exact example to implement Firebase with it so i used core node to explain it , I will be updating this answer after i finished with this method and sails + Firebase

```
res.created()
```

hope this helps you in your work